# ie/firefox and flash: what's the refresh algorithm

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, firefox, actionscript

I made a flash and embed it into a webpage. I use the browser to test the flash, an intersting thing, after I upload the flash into the server, and press F5 to refresh the browser, the browser still use the old one, I can't enforce the browser to use the new flash swf file!

How can I tell browser to use the new swf?

Comment: btw I can refresh after I deleting all the temporary files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending a random (and meaningless) query string to the URL of the SWF. That way, the browser thinks it's a new file and will download it again from the server.

Comment: that will make it to download everytime? I don't want the user to download it if I didn't make modification.

Comment: Just change the variable when the file changes, or version your filenames and change that when you update the flash asset...

Comment: @pharalia - exactly...a version number on the query string should ensure that the file is cached until it changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you append random query string to your swf file in javascript, as Tim suggests, following things will happen:

- swf will be loaded every time from server (no caching at all)
- browser cache will be populated with copies of your swf (one after each request, if browser is not smart enough to compare file contents)

I think it's best to append version to your swf and update it (like name1.0.swf, name1.1.swf and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to delete the browser cache, if you don't want to rename your file everytime you make a modification.

Comment: The question it slightly misleading the way it's currently worded, the point is how to do it for _other users_ and not just yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you can use FireBug for disable the browser cache.

Comment: You don't need FireBug to disable the cache. You can't do it directly in the preferences. Keep in mind too that FireBug _should_ be used as a development tool, and ultimately the point of the question is to figure out how to have _other users's_ browsers load the new SWF file.

Comment: I meant to say you _can_, not can't, disable the cache in the Firefox preferences if you set the storage to 0 MB.